# Java, Create array if it doesn't already exist

Tags: java

I couldn't find anything on that while googling
so
I want to create an array only if it doesn't already exists.

EDIT: I mean not initialized

I know how to check for values in the array

Should be simple but I'm stuck

best regards

```
static long f(long n) {
    int m = (int)n;
    **if (serie == null) {

   long[] serie = new long[40];
    }**
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n==1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        long asdf = f(n-1)- 2*(f(n-2)) + n;
        return asdf;
    }
}
```

something like that
a recursive function and I want to save the values in an array

Comment: What do you mean by "if it doesn't already exist"? If it's null? Empty?

Comment: which array are you referring to then? can you show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
if (values == null)
{
    values = new int[10];
}
```

or something like that? If not, please edit your question to provide more information.

EDIT: Okay, judging by the updated question, I suspect you ought to have two methods:

```
static long f(long n)
{
    return f(n, new long[40]);
}

static long f(long n, long[] serie)
{
    // Code as before, but when you recurse, pass in serie as well
}
```

(Note that your current code doesn't *use* `serie` at all.)

Comment: yes,but using that I always get this error:                   cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable serie
location: class Bsp17
        if (serie == null) {
            ^
1 error

Comment: @Franz: Well it's pretty hard to diagnose that without seeing the rest of the context.

Comment: yeah I know, I just put the array bit in to show what the question and function where about

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the `serie` array but it is not yet declared. First declare it and then use it, as you want.

Comment: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable serie
location: class Bsp17
        if (serie == null) {
            ^
1 error, always this error

Comment: This is a compiler error, which means the `serie` array is out of scope.

Comment: yeah but I wanna declare it only if it hasn't already been declared, or is that not possible

Comment: @Franz: You should be able to tell whether or not it's been declared, by looking at the code. You can't "optionally" declare a variable.

Comment: @Franz - You are misunderstanding a core programming concept. Something must be declared before it is even tried to be used. Otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Comment: ""You can't "optionally" declare a variable."" that answers my question thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
if(array==null){
//create new array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are, if you use a variable in java, it is initialized. So you probably want to check if that variable, an array in this case, is null. Not only that, you can and probably should check if it is an array. Arrays are objects in java. So you could do something like this for an array:

```
if(!obj.getClass().isArray())
```